# How to get users from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I recently learned about developing applications, and I have difficulty adding Firestore user accounts to the task application, I use flutter and [flutter_chips_input plugins](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chips_input). is there an example to solve this?

```
ChipsInput(
    initialValue: [
        AppProfile('John Doe', 'jdoe@flutter.io', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg')
    ],
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Select People",
    ),
    maxChips: 3,
    findSuggestions: (String query) {
        if (query.length != 0) {
            var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
            return mockResults.where((profile) {
                return profile.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) || profile.email.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
            }).toList(growable: false)
                ..sort((a, b) => a.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(lowercaseQuery)
                    .compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery)));
        } else {
            return const <AppProfile>[];
        }
    },
    onChanged: (data) {
        print(data);
    },
    chipBuilder: (context, state, profile) {
        return InputChip(
            key: ObjectKey(profile),
            label: Text(profile.name),
            avatar: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
            ),
            onDeleted: () => state.deleteChip(profile),
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        );
    },
    suggestionBuilder: (context, state, profile) {
        return ListTile(
            key: ObjectKey(profile),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
            ),
            title: Text(profile.name),
            subtitle: Text(profile.email),
            onTap: () => state.selectSuggestion(profile),
        );
    },
)
```

Comment: _adding Firestore user accounts to the task application_ what do you mean by this?

Comment: sorry about that, I mean I have a user in firestore and want to add that user to my new task apps

Comment: username
"msoleh"
email
"msoleh399@gmail.com"
fullName
"Muhammad Solihin"
id
"106807126702075940257"
photoUrl
"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PMvWjGkMFp0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3retWXrFpTtVPpT9PoBrzQS1eeB63Q/s96-c/photo.jpg"
(string)
status
""
timestamp
January 15, 2020 at 4:18:14 PM UTC+7

Comment: Do you want to populate a widget with your existing users?

Comment: @easeccy yes, how do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are implementing Firebase in your product, be aware of that you are writing client-side code. The code you write will be running on individual user devices. Fetching all the users should not be implemented in user end. Therefore you can't fetch the authorized users in the app directly.

It can be achieveable with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). You can deploy Javascript or Typescript code to the cloud to have dynamic behaviour on your backend. You can use [Auth Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) and keep track of users in your database. For instance, you can attach a callback function to `onCreate()`. It will get triggered when:

- A user creates an email account and password.
- A user signs in for the first time using a federated identity provider.
- The developer creates an account using the Firebase Admin SDK.
- A user signs in to a new anonymous auth session for the first time.

with a `UserRecord` object. Then you can save the information you want to the Firestore, most of the time under the `users` collection or similar. Now you have users in your Firestore database, you can use them in the app, with properly configured [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) of course. You can fetch them all, fetch spesific user or users with queries and so on.

Comment: yes I still try cloud firestore, but I have not been able to implement it on the widget. still getting an error

Comment: What do you mean?